# how to add datagrid control to wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express, and I don't know how to add a Datagrid control to my Project.

When I try to add PresentationCore.dll to my application it throws this exception:

```
Type Universe Cannot Resolve Assembly:system.xaml,version=4.0.0.0,culture=neutral,publicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Can someone please help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Datagrid control available in the base Windows Phone SDK. You'll have to find a 3rd party control for that.

Also, if I'm correct, that's a WPF assembly, so you won't be able to add it to a Silverlight/Windows Phone project!